# Is it possible to control a chromecast or phillips hue from a dialogflow app

Tags: chromecast, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

it is possible to control devices like chromecast or phillips hue from a dialogflow.com application? I want to build something like this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFV1eTeeFis

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control a Chromecast from a Dialogflow app. For controlling Philips Hue, there is not a direct way to do it. However, Philips Hue has an API that you should be able to use.